# jQuery smooth scrolling script doesn't work in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have this jQuery code intended for smooth scrolling. I tried this on Firefox, and it works as intended. However, when I try it in Chrome it does not work at all. Any ideas? Thanks so much!

```
$('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
}, 500);
return false;
```

});